# I can't access http://localhost:8080 when I run docker-compose up With MongoDB and NestJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, dockerfile, nestjs

Here is the `Dockerfile` I created

```
# Base image
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install 

# Bundle app source
COPY . .


EXPOSE 8080

# Creates a "dist" folder with the production build
RUN npm run build

# Start the server using the production build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

File `docker-compose.yaml` I using  `network_mode: "host"`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    # network_mode: "host"
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - "27018:27017"
        # restart: always
        environment: 
              ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
              ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example 
        # network_mode: "host"
    api:
        image: image_name
        build: . 
        depends_on: 
            - mongo
        environment: 
            NODE_ENV: development
            PORT: 3000
            USERNAME : root,
            PASSWORD : example
        ports:
            - "8080:3000"
        network_mode: "host"
```

Finally, I set the TypeORM configuration to match with the Docker Compose file:

```
@Module({
  imports: [ TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'mongodb',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27018,
    database: 'admin',
    entities: [],
    synchronize: true,
  })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

when running it works fine until i go to http://localhost:8000 it can't be accessed. I am using windows 11 os. Can anyone help me to solve this problem I have tried a lot. Thanks everyone

Comment: [port mapping MUST NOT be used with network_mode: host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running on 3000, if you want to use docker-compose port mapping, you should expose 3000 ( not 8080 ).

If you are using network_mode: host, then you will be able to access it on http://localhost:3000.